# JNI GetPrimitiveArrayCritical causes JVM Crash

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvm-hotspot, jvm-crash

I have a java program calling a JNI function to perform computation on a byte array, returning a long array of. The programs runs on Oracle JDK 1.8.0_221. To test the throughput, I run the code for multiple iterations on the same byte array of size 64M, using JMH 1.21

The java side code is as following

```
public long[] compute(byte[] input, int resultSize) {
    long[] result = new long[resultSize];
    nativeCompute(input, result);
    return result;
}

native void nativeCompute(byte[] input, long[] output);
```

The JNI code simply obtains pointers from Java arrays and pass it to the compute function

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativeCompute_nativeCompute
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject self, jbyteArray input, jlongArray result) {

//  uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *) env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(input, 0);
//  uint64_t *localres = (uint64_t *) env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(result, 0);
    jbyte *data = env->GetByteArrayElements(input, 0);
    jlong *localres = env->GetLongArrayElements(result, 0);

    compute((uint8_t *) data, (uint64_t *) localres);

//  env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(input, data, JNI_ABORT);
//  env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(result, localres, JNI_COMMIT);
    env->ReleaseLongArrayElements(result, localres, JNI_COMMIT);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(input, data, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

I use `GetByteArrayElements` and `GetLongArrayElements` to fetch pointers from java array, and the program works fine.

To avoid array copy, I try to switch to `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical/ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical`, as can be seen in the code that is commented out. There is a 15% performance improvement, but JVM crashs after running for some (30-150) iterations. The error log is as below

```
# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:12:30
# Fork: 1 of 5
# Warmup Iteration   1: 7.436 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe4b14ca554, pid=14023, tid=0x00007fe49baa2700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_221-b11) (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.221-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x987554][thread 140620183496448 also had an error]
[thread 140619839837952 also had an error]
  oopDesc* PSPromotionManager::copy_to_survivor_space<false>(oopDesc*)+0x204
#
```

When I switch back to `Get<XX>ArrayElements`, this error is gone. But I still want to get the 15% performance improvement from `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical`.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

## Update Aug 20, 2019

Thanks everyone for your suggestion! I have tried as you suggested and here's some update.

1. I added code to check the pointers for NULL. They are not null.
2. The error only occurs in JMH environment. When I run the code as standalone and repeat for 2000 iterations, there's no error.
3. I commented out the compute, and the error is gone. Seems like the crash is caused by array overflow. I double check the code and found that
   when the number of input elements is a multiple of 64, my code will accidentally cross boundary of the result array. I fix that bug and now the error is gone. I should have double checked the code to avoid this kind of silly mistake.

Although it is still not clear why the error only occurs in JMH environment, I think we have found the root cause and thank you all for the help!

Comment: 1. You should check whether the pointer returned by `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical` is `NULL`. If this is the case, the VM ran out of memory. 2. Does it work when you comment out the internal call to `compute`? (Just to make sure that the error is not caused by the `compute` function...)

Comment: Might be irrelevant, but you never know: the PrimitiveArrayCritical case releases the arrays in a different order.

Comment: You can also avoid a copy by using `ByteBuffer` instead of `byte[]`, as JNI has specific functions for accessing the backing array.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, something fishy is going o inside your compute stuff. If I do very simple test, with the very same approach you have, I don't encounter any issues.

Also, it's quite important that `compute` doesn't do anything `JNI` related. `PrimitiveArray` comes with the price.

Of course, for 100 loops over the same function (as in here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo053) you can see clear benefits in speedup

```
Access via PrimitiveArray
       14.64 real        14.55 user         0.12 sys
Access via ArrayElements
       51.55 real        35.94 user        15.13 sys
```

Two and half times faster. Anyway, as `PrimitiveArray` comes with the cost

> After calling GetPrimitiveArrayCritical, the native code 
>   should not run for an extended period of time before it calls 
>   ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical.

I'd rethink whether using `PrimitiveArray` for this kind of array sizes is what you really want.

**Update**

Ups! It looks like it was solved while I was preparing the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks. The compute function currently takes a stable 100 ms to process the 64MB data, so I guess it's not urgent to switch to ByteBuffer for now. But I will think about this seriously.